# Can't get the value of a certain Excel file using OPENpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to load a cell value A2 to my console. However I keep getting this instead. Anything I am missing?

[image: Cell 'Sheet1'.A2]

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

Value = sheet['A2']
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openpyxl functions in a way that

```
sheet['A2]
```

points to the cell itself.

If you like to put a value into 'A2':

```
sheet['A2'].value = 123
```

Now, to retrieve the value from 'A2' use:

```
testVariable = sheet['A2'].value
>>> 123
```

I hope, this helps you.

Take care

Comment: Thanks that help I was following the Youtuber Mosh and thats all he did was that but now i got the value